# I am trying to write an equation in LaTeX and i have an error

Tags: latex

> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage{amsmath}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{equation*}
>      $
>     f(x)  =  x^2$
>
> \end{equation*}
>
> \end{document}
>
> #And this is the error:
>
> ! Display math should end with $$.
>
> l.11 $
>
> ?

Comment: This question might be better put in the LaTeX stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $ signs from the line with your equation in it.

It should read

```
\begin{equation*} f(x) = x^2
```

I think.

Comment: I did it and I have the error:  ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11

Comment: This error usually appears because you used a $ somewhere previously that needs to be matched by an ending $. Try this: look at the lines before line 11. Are there any $ that you see that maybe need to be matched with something? If you hit enter in your console, will your file keep compiling? If so, keep hitting enter, and if there is weird spacing after this, it thinks it's still in math mode, and not closed correctly. Additionally, it might be line spacing, so make sure the equation is on a new line to the begin equation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation environment automatically sets math mode. No need to place additonal dollar signs.

Comment: Now I have this error:  ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11

Comment: `f(x) = x^2` should be placed on a new line